# UIPrerenderedIcon being ignored for XCode 4.2.1 in Simulator or Device

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I've set UIPrerenderedIcon to true in my info.plist file but both the simulator and device (running iOS 5.0.1) are ignoring the value...

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
```

Any ideas what I can do? I've tried Clean -> Build but that didn't solve it either...

Comment: The syntax looks the same as mine which works in iOS 5.0.1 and on Simulator. Can you post the whole file and we can have a look?

Comment: make sure you're viewing the keys as their actual value rather than localized names and see if that key is the actual key that is being set

Comment: There's only one info.plist file - Doesn't matter how I view the file (either as property list or raw source code), the value is there, set as true.

Comment: found the problem - solution posted below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the issue.

In iOS 5 it groups your icons together in a dictionary. You need to expand the item in your plist called "Icon Files (iOS 5)", then "Primary Icon". In there you will see another UIPrerenderedIcon value setting.

Change that, and solved!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I was looking through one of my app's info.plist (that successfully prevented the glossy effect) to compare with a new one (that did had the flag "ignored"). Now that I saw your post, I noticed the first app does not have the "Icon Files (iOS5)" entry (it's older than iOS5), so I'm guessing it defaults back to the "regular" key.

Comment: With recent versions of Xcode (4.5, for example), you can set this key by selecting the project, selecting the target, selecting "Summary", and in the "App Icons" section there is a checkbox labeled "Prerendered". Check it, and the setting will be added to the right place in Info.plist.